# How to properly configure alias directive in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, alias

I have been trying to configure multiple webapp on my nginx webserver but I can't get working one Laravel app that requires $document_root set to laravel public folder. 
I am currently trying to configure it using alias directive but for an obscure reason this doesn't work. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;


    set $root_path '/var/www/html';
    root $root_path;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location /paperwork {
        alias /var/www/html/paperwork/frontend/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
        #location ~ \.php {
        #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        #   #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        #   #fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        #}
    }

    #location @paperwork {
    #   rewrite /paperwork/(.*)$ /paperwork/index.php/$1 last;
    #}

    location / {

    }


    location /wallabag {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location /laverna {
        try_files $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }



    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

To test my "alias" config I put a 'test.php' files in /var/www/html/paperwork/frontend/public/test.php and tried to access it via https://IP/paperwork/test.php. I get a 404 error and nothing in nginx error log. 
If I try https://IP/paperwork/frontend/public/test.php in browser it displays the test.php file without errors. 
Nothing change if I uncomment try_files line in php location.

If I copy test.php to /var/www/html/paperwork/test2.php and access to https://IP/paperwork/test2.php the file is displayed without errors so I can see here that alias is not working as there is not a test2.php in paperwork public directory.

I can have a different behaviour if I uncomment php location inside paperwork location. With this, requests like https://IP/paperwork/test.php do not display a 404 but a blank screen.

I have been through a lot of forums / questions related to this but I couldn't get a working config for a simple task like displaying test.php...

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for such a helpful question.. sir, you made my day

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems that a wrong request was sent for php files. When alias is used it is recommend to use $request_filename instead of $fastcgi_script_name.

Here is my location block :

```
location /paperwork {

      alias /var/www/html/paperwork/frontend/public;
      #try_files $uri $uri/;
      location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          include fastcgi_params;                       
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          #fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      }
}
```

This solved my problem for my 'test.php' file which is now executed while reaching https://IP/paperwork/test.php. So alias is working and php is well executed. 
I still have a problem when trying to reach 'index.php' (which is my laravel app index). File is found but instead of executing it is downloaded. So when I reach https://IP/paperwork/index.php I get a login file downloaded which is index.php file. I get same behaviour if I try /paperwork/index.php/login or /paperwork/login.

Comment: Yes! thank you.  The key was using `$request_filename`.  Every other example had `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name` but that didn't work.

Comment: I am having the same issue and not able to to execute the index.php file. I also tried setting up index index.php in my location but no luck.

Comment: directive `alias /some/path;` + `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` needs directive `index index.php;`at a location level to work with `index.php` also

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to make this (or anything else) work with `index` files. Adding `index index.php;` will just download the file.

Comment: OK, important note: file downloads are __cached__! Adding `index index.php;` to the `/paperwork` location does work. But you need to clear the cache or index.php will not get executed and will be downloaded instead.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
location /api/ {
     index  index.php index.html index.htm;
     alias /app/www/;
     location ~* "\.php$" {
         try_files      $uri =404;
         fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
     }
 }
```

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/