# nginx redirection to sibling folder and serve php not working

Tags: php, nginx

I have my nginx home at **/opt/nginx**, inside there are **site1** and **mail** folders, **site1** has **html** folder that is a wordpress installation and **mail** is a webmail site, both of them must be proxied to php-fpm, ***site1/html*** works like a charm no problem at all.

I have the **domain1.com** and my server delivers **site1/html** content when **domain1.com** is requested.

What I want to do is, when ***domain1.com/mail*** is requested, serve the content of **mail** folder (sibling of **site1**).  If I left a ***index.html*** file inside mail, when **domail1.com/mail** is requested, **index.html** is served to the client without problem but if I try to deliver **mail/index.php**, ***404 error rise instead***,  what am I doing wrong? below my config:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/domain1.com.conf

```
server {
.
.
.

root /opt/nginx/site1/html;
index index.html index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /mail {
    root /opt/nginx/;
    try_files $uri $uri/mail mail/index.php;        
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    # SECURITY : Zero day Exploit Protection
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066463/nginx-alias-directive-not-working-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested location blocks to invoke PHP scripts which are in a different document root.

Like this:

```
root /opt/nginx/site1/html;
index index.html index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ^~ /mail {
    root /opt/nginx;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /mail/index.php;        

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;    
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Notice the `^~` modifier which allows the nested PHP block to take precedence over the outer PHP block. I also removed the path info code which was not being used.

Comment: Worked like a charm, as I didn't realize, I managed to bypass my problem doing a soft link:

cd /opt/nginx/site1/html
ln -s /opt/nginx/mail mail

as mail now is inside /, no modification to config file was need so I left it as:

root /opt/nginx/site1/html;
index index.html index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

unfortunately doing so, I needed to ask my client for permission in order to add the soft link,  now I can manage all in config file.